# Cocoapods gitignore not working in swift3 xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, git, cocoapods

Currently hitting a problem with gitignore

[image]

My .gitignore file has even these.
.gitignore located at my project's root directory.

And I get these.
[image]

I am looking into this for a long time but not much info about this in the internet yet. Any help?
Thank you.

Comment: This may be because Pods directory already in your Git repository before you add it to .gitignore.

Comment: Thanks for the info!